# Bitnami httpd using 100 percent CPU because of requests from localhost

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, cpu, cpu-usage, bitnami

I'm running Bitnami on EC2, Ubuntu 12.04. My CPU has been pinned to 100% for 2 days because of http requests, but from the localhost. In the access log, I see this:

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2014:14:14:56 +0000] "POST /agent/v2 HTTP/1.1" 301 -

These are the only requests, and they are spaced out at an interval of 3-7 seconds each, continuously..

I ran strace of the httpd pid, and I see each one of these requests appears to go through my entire bitnami directory structure. I cannot figure out what is making this request though.

*UPDATE* - I created an "agent/v2" directory and put a blank index.php file in there, and that solved the CPU usage. However, the request is still being made, more frequently now - about 1-2 times a second. I'm guessing it is some kind of redirect loop that was just slowed down by CPU starvation - what would cause this kind of redirect?

Comment: You running Apache? Have you check the configs?

Comment: What should I look for? I don't see the "agent/v2" directory being configured anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you a cron job or process running that is making the queries to 127.0.0.1.

1. Run some of the following: `ps -Af`. Check if there's any process that jumps out that may be making the requests.
2. Check the files under `/etc/cron.d`. See if any of the files actually has a job that maybe running constantly. Like every minute.
3. As `root` and `whatever-default-bitnami-user` run: `crontab -l`, and see if there's any cron job running as a user.

   - If there are any cronjobs you can edit them running `crontab -e`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rico
I'm at the point where I'm randomly running strace on processes listed from ps just to see who is making the request - nothing yet.
The only job in cron was a bitnami reporting agent, which I have disabled, but it did not help. 
It's strange, because I have another instance running essentially the same setup that does not have this issue.

The search continues for this rogue process..